# Cleanest way to check for consistency of multiple values in an object list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to determine if several values of objects in a collection are all the same or not.  I've came up with two major ways to do it; but neither is entirely satisfactory.  In both cases I'm doing the check by comparing each objects values against those in the first one in the collection.  The first is to iterate the collection checking each value at the same time:

```
bool string1Varies = false;
bool string2Varies = false;
bool string3Varies = false;
bool string4Varies = false;


foreach (Foo foo in myFooList)
{
    if (foo.string1 != myFooList[0].string1)
        string1Varies = true;
    if (foo.string2 != myFooList[0].string2)
        string2Varies = true;
    if (foo.string3 != myFooList[0].string3)
        string3Varies = true;
    if (foo.string4 != myFooList[0].string4)
        string4Varies = true;

    //optionally break if all 4 bools are true
}
```

If the normal case is that all the values are the same, that approach has the advantage of only iterating the collection once, but it somewhat verbose.  I could improve its performance if all 4 varying was somewhat common by adding a check to break the loop; but this would add more overhead to the iteration and make it even longer.

Alternately I could compute each bool individually using Linq:

```
bool string1Varies = myFooList.All(foo => foo.string1 = myFooList[0].string1);
bool string2Varies = myFooList.All(foo => foo.string2 = myFooList[0].string2);
bool string3Varies = myFooList.All(foo => foo.string3 = myFooList[0].string3);
bool string4Varies = myFooList.All(foo => foo.string4 = myFooList[0].string4);
```

This has the advantage of being concise and failing fast if a change occurs early in the collection, but if the values are the same ends up iterating the entire collection 4 times.

Is there any way I could get the best of both worlds by computing all 4 values in a single easily readable Linq operation?

Comment: So, you want to check if all the objects in the list have string1..string4 different than the first object of the list. Is that your goal?

Comment: @Edin I'm validating non-normalized data.  Each of string1...4 should be the same in each object, but might not be.  There's nothing special about the first object in the collection, I singled it out as a reference purely for convenience.  The last object would work equally as well; because there's no fixed number of objects (other than being at least 1) using any other position in the collection would be problematic.

Comment: Do you want to know a) is there any object in the collection which has at least one of the string1..string4 values different than other objects in the collection? or b) is there any object in the collection which has all string1..string4 values different than other objects in the collection?

Comment: Do you need to know which string varies or only that a string varies?

Comment: I need to know if each string varies.  The 4 booleans are the results I need.  Does string 1 have the same value everywhere or does it vary, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note that there are no (practical) optimizations to be had making this faster. You will need Θ(n) loop iterations (with a few assumptions) to perform this check.

Your conditions have no dependencies on each other so they must remain independent. A verbosity change you could make involves rewriting your conditions in your first solution.

```
string1Varies |= foo.string1 != myFooList[0].string1;
string2Varies |= foo.string2 != myFooList[0].string2;
string3Varies |= foo.string3 != myFooList[0].string3;
string4Varies |= foo.string4 != myFooList[0].string4;
```

I don't see anything else than that.

Answer (score 0):

As properly pointed out by Shoe, if your comparisons and discrepancies are completely independent, as far as I know there is no way to do that in more performant and concise way, than a foreach statement (your first solution). However, your Linq solution could be improved by using `Any` instead of `All`:

```
bool string1Varies = myFooList.Any(foo => foo.string1 != myFooList[0].string1);
bool string2Varies = myFooList.Any(foo => foo.string2 != myFooList[0].string2);
bool string3Varies = myFooList.Any(foo => foo.string3 != myFooList[0].string3);
bool string4Varies = myFooList.Any(foo => foo.string4 != myFooList[0].string4);
```

This way, in case one of the values is different, you do not end up iterating an entire collection. But note that it is still performing worse than the foreach solution, due to multiple iterations.

Answer (score -2):

For comparison of any difference in the properties within the object:

```
IEnumerable<long> hashed = myList.Select(
    (item) => new string[] { item.String1, item.String2, item.String3, item.String4 }
    .Aggregate<string, long>(0, (runningHash, actual) => 
        (runningHash + actual.GetHashCode()) * 2654435761 % (int)Math.Pow(2, 32)));

bool areAllSame = hashed.Skip(1)
    .FirstOrDefault((item) => item != hashed.First()) == null;
```

What it does: It creates a running hash function (with knuth hash algorithm) over all properties. GetHashCode does not have to be cryptographic to make collisions improbable. Collisions in this domain are *very* improbable but of course not impossible. Otherwise you can always use a cryptographic hash function to be on the safe side.
The order of the strings is also covered as the running value gets rehashed for each value.

Dont complain about the details, take it as another approach. --> One Hash over all the properties which makes the equality directly comparable in one loop.

This is O(n*m) in worst case... (m = number of properties)

Comment: Won't work.  I need values for each separate member/property I'm testing.  Also I believe that Distinct will iterate the entire collection in every case.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your new code is supposed to be doing; but it appears to be generating a single value for each object.  I need separate same/different values for each of the values I'm looking at.

Comment: Also, string.GetHashCode() does not use a cryptographic hash; so assuming collisions are statistically impossible unwise.  "Test1".GetHashCode() = -1556460260, "Test2".GetHashCode() = -1556460257, "Test3".GetHashCode() = -1556460258  Beyond that, adding hashes like that would treat two objects with the same strings in different orders as being equivalent.